# Microsoft graph - Insufficient privileges when trying to get user info

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to get user information from Active Directory (email, phone number and assigned groups) using Microsoft graph and implicit flow in angular + asp.net web api application after user logges into the system.

Now we've set up some privileges for the application registered in Azure AD and all the code seems to be working fine using below set up.

[image]

The problem is those permissions seem high just for reading profile info and groups of a single user.

According to microsoft documentation delegated User.Read should be enough - [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#permissions) but after changing to below setup and removing User.Read.All for application

[image]

below error is thrown:

```
{
"StatusCode":500,
"Message":"Code: Authorization_RequestDenied Message: Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.
Inner error: AdditionalData: date: x request-id: x client-request-id: x ClientRequestId: x "
}
```

The error is thrown when calling Users from graphClient:

```
    GraphServiceClient graphClient = GetClient();

    return await graphClient.Users[userObjectId].Request()
        .GetAsync();

private GraphServiceClient GetClient()
{
    IConfidentialClientApplication confidentialClientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
                .Create(ADClientId)
                .WithTenantId(TenantId)
                .WithClientSecret(ApplicationSecret)
                .Build();

    ClientCredentialProvider authProvider = new ClientCredentialProvider(confidentialClientApplication);

    GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);

    return graphClient;
}
```

Now I'm not sure how to limit those privileges. Whether there is something incorrect with the flow, the C# code or maybe the privileges are incorrect.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`User.Read` Delegated permission allows users to sign-in to the app, and allows the app to read the profile of **signed-in users**. It also allows the app to read basic company information of **signed-in users**.

So you can only get `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me` or `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/user/{userObjectId of the signed-in user}` with this permission.

If you want to get other user's information, please use `User.ReadBasic.All` or `User.Read.All` Delegated permission (based on your needs). Please note you need to add **Delegated permission** rather than Application permission.

[image]

Reference [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference#delegated-permissions-65).

Comment: Hey. Thanks for the quick answer. Unfortunately I'm still getting Forbidden after adding User.Read.All delegated permissions. For some reason it has to be application. Also I would assume that the code I provided graphClient.Users[userObjectId].Request() would translate to user/{userObjectId} http request

Comment: @MateuszMigała So you are using [client credential flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=CS#client-credentials-provider) rather than implicit flow based on your code. In this case you should assign **Application permission**.

Comment: Yes it seems that your comment is the answer to this question. Another developer implemented the flow and since we use implicit flow for our JWT tokens and client - API I assumed that this is the same case with Microsopht graph and it is different. I'm looking into the documentation to check which flow would be suitable for us to use: SPA angular client App authenticating to APIs using Identity Server Asp.NET Core MVC. Identity server is the application that needs to access Microsopht Graph Azure AD with delegated permissions. If you would have any suggestions they are more than welcome